# Get browser versions using KQL

Tags: security, kql

I wanted to get browsers versions using KQL query in Microsoft Defender for Endpoint. I tried the following but results nothing. I couldn't find a good documentation to write a query to find such information. Any guidance please.

`DeviceEvents | where ActionType == "BrowserEvent" | project DeviceName, DeviceId, Timestamp, BrowserName, BrowserVersion`

`DeviceEvents | where ActionType == "BrowserEvent" | project DeviceName, DeviceId, Timestamp, BrowserName, BrowserVersion`

I wanted to get browser versions to find users who uses outdated browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate the query in my own Azure Portal, but with some basic syntax you should be able to create a simple overview of the browser versions and it's count.

**Summarize used browser versions**

```
DeviceEvents 
| where ActionType == "BrowserEvent"
| summarize count() by BrowserName, BrowserVersion
```

**Search for users using outdated browser versions**

```
DeviceEvents 
| where ActionType == "BrowserEvent" 
| where BrowserVersion contains "X.XX" 
     or BrowserVersion contains "X.XX"
| summarize count() by DeviceName, DeviceId, Browsername, BrowserVersion
```

**Timeline of users using specific browser version per day**

```
DeviceEvents
| where Timestamp > ago(14d)
| where ActionType == "BrowserEvent"
| where BrowserVersion contains "X.XX" or BrowserVersion contains "X.XX"
| extend info = strcat(DeviceName, ": ", BrowserName)
| summarize count() by bin(Timestamp, 1d), info
| render columnchart
```

Haven't really tested these in Log Analytics, but this should give a good start to look for specific information.